# How to dynamically create pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a script where I would like to end out with 5 dataframes - the script is being handover to the marketing department, so I would like to avoid additional coding.

```
tables = [onegram, twogram, threegram, fourgram, original]
def calc_rate(table):
    table['Interaction rate'] = table['Interactions'] / table['Impr.']
    table['Interaction rate'] = table['Interaction rate'].replace(np.nan, 0)
    table['Interaction rate'] = table['Interaction rate'].replace(np.inf, 0)
    table['Conv. rate'] = table['Conversions'] / table['Interactions']
    table['Conv. rate'] = table['Conv. rate'].replace(np.nan, 0)
    table['Conv. rate'] = table['Conv. rate'].replace(np.inf, 0)
    table['Cost / conv'] = table['Cost'] / table['Conversions']
    table['Cost / conv'] = table['Cost / conv'].replace(np.nan, 0)
    table['Cost / conv'] = table['Cost / conv'].replace(np.inf, 0)
    table['Avg. cost'] = table['Cost'] / table['Interactions']
    table['Avg. cost'] = table['Avg. cost'].replace(np.nan, 0)
    table['Avg. cost'] = table['Avg. cost'].replace(np.inf, 0)
    
    i = 1
    for table in tables: 
        calc_rate(table)
        print("table {} is done".format(i))
        i+=1
```

This is the last part of the code (working)
Now I want to create a dataframe for each of them taking top 100 sorted by Interactions - something like this inside the same function:

```
       for table in tables: 
           table.add_suffix('_interaction_sorted') = table.sort_values(by="Interactions", ascending=False).head(100)
```

I would like to end up with:

```
onegram_interactions_sorted
twogram_interactions_sorted
threegram_interactions_sorted
fourgram_interactions_sorted
original_interactions_sorted
```

it obviously does not work, but how could i make it work??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table1 = table.sort_values(by="Interactions", ascending=False).head(100)
table1 = table1.add_suffix('_interaction_sorted')
```

or if you want same name

```
table = table.sort_values(by="Interactions", ascending=False).head(100)
table = table.add_suffix('_interaction_sorted')
```

Comment: No that does not work .. 
I want to create 5 new dataframes in a loop so i end up with: 
onegram_interactions_sorted
twogram_interactions_sorted
threegram_interactions_sorted 
etc.

Comment: You are trying to assign dataframe to some variable which is not allowed. So what you can do is,  save required dataframe to desired name in suitable format like using `df.to_csv('path/file_name.csv')` in your case file_name is 'onegram_interaction_sorted'.